# Pros and Cons files for php, using include()

Tags: php, include

Simply. I have an empty page looking like

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("footer.php");
?>
```

That gives navbar, config files, pageload took: blabla. And stuff like that. But, what's the pros, and cons of doing so? Instead of, examplewise, putting it all into one file.

Comment: The two answers given are spot on. You want to keep your code centralized and modular (DRY: Dont Repeat Yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest pro I could think of is keeping code clean, and rather then necessarily copying and pasting the code in each individual file you can have it all in one place. Makes it a ton easier to make small changes.

The largest con I can think of is if you're looking for an error that happens to be in a different file. Since php pages are compiled server side you cannot just click view source to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The pro to using an include file is that you can reference the same code over and over again and not have to retype it (and later edit multiple sources if you want to make a change).

The only con I can think of is if you break the single file later on, then you potentially break every file that it's included in.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't it send a http request, sending headers, and everything, making it slower? Or is that so small, it's not noticable?

Comment: I know, but a large amount of them :).

Answer (score 0):

Pros:

**Structure** You get a better view of your code. The code will be more clean.

**Reuse code** You can reuse your code. Rather then put a database connection in every single file you can have one file with the database connection that you include.

Cons:

There aren't pretty much any cons that you really need to consider. Perhaps a bit harder on the error tracking, but definitely nothing you need to worry about. **In my opinion You should definitely seperate your code in different files.**

About Performance:

You will not lack any kind of performance or speed that is noticable. Everyone does use include in or another way. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself play a role here).